# Calculate and append column totals of select columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, janitor

I have the following code for calculating certain quantities of interest, specifically the sum of the two right-most columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

m = c(0, 0.8, 2.3, 4.1, 2.1)
l = c(0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.75, 0.25)

mytable = data.frame(l, m)
rownames(mytable) = paste("Group", 1:5)

# Initial population
n0 = c(1,1,1,1,1)

mytable = mytable %>%
  mutate(lm = l * m) %>%
  mutate(n = n0) %>%
  mutate(offspring = lm * n) %>%
  adorn_totals("row")
```

This gives the following output:

```
> mytable
     l   m    lm n offspring
   0.3 0.0 0.000 1     0.000
   0.8 0.8 0.640 1     0.640
   0.9 2.3 2.070 1     2.070
  0.75 4.1 3.075 1     3.075
  0.25 2.1 0.525 1     0.525
 Total 9.3 6.310 5     6.310
```

I have the following issues:

- How to isolate the column totals for specific columns? In my case, I would like the column totals for just columns `n` and `offspring`. I read the documentation for the `adorn_totals()` function but I could not figure out how to do this.
- The row names assigned are missing. How can I make the row names appear and have the word "Total" as the row name for the new row of column totals?
- The row total does not appear for the first column, which is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to convert the columns other than the required columns to `character` class and then change it later.  Regarding the row names, `tibble` doesn't allow for row names.  We may need to create a column first with `rownames_to_column`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(janitor)
out <- mytable %>% 
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
    mutate(lm = l *m, n = n0, offspring = lm * n) %>% 
    mutate(across(-c(n, offspring), as.character)) %>% 
    adorn_totals('row', fill = NA) %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
> out
      rn    l   m    lm n offspring
 Group 1 0.30 0.0 0.000 1     0.000
 Group 2 0.80 0.8 0.640 1     0.640
 Group 3 0.90 2.3 2.070 1     2.070
 Group 4 0.75 4.1 3.075 1     3.075
 Group 5 0.25 2.1 0.525 1     0.525
   Total   NA  NA    NA 5     6.310
> str(out)
Classes ‘tabyl’ and 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ rn       : chr  "Group 1" "Group 2" "Group 3" "Group 4" ...
 $ l        : num  0.3 0.8 0.9 0.75 0.25 NA
 $ m        : num  0 0.8 2.3 4.1 2.1 NA
 $ lm       : num  0 0.64 2.07 3.075 0.525 ...
 $ n        : int  1 1 1 1 1 5
 $ offspring: num  0 0.64 2.07 3.075 0.525 ...
 - attr(*, "core")='data.frame':    5 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ rn       : chr [1:5] "Group 1" "Group 2" "Group 3" "Group 4" ...
  ..$ l        : chr [1:5] "0.3" "0.8" "0.9" "0.75" ...
  ..$ m        : chr [1:5] "0" "0.8" "2.3" "4.1" ...
  ..$ lm       : chr [1:5] "0" "0.64" "2.07" "3.075" ...
  ..$ n        : num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
  ..$ offspring: num [1:5] 0 0.64 2.07 3.075 0.525
 - attr(*, "tabyl_type")= chr "two_way"
 - attr(*, "totals")= chr "row"
```

Answer (score 6):

To your first and third points: you can control which columns are totaled by specifying column names to the `...` argument of `adorn_totals()`.  Using `...` requires specifying values for the other arguments, even if they're empty, thus the `,,,,` below to accept the default values for those arguments.

The first column is skipped by default, as this is usually a group ID (like your rownames), but you can specify that it should be totaled.

Here is how you'd total the columns `l`, `n`, and `offspring`:

```
mytable %>%
  mutate(lm = l * m) %>%
  mutate(n = n0) %>%
  mutate(offspring = lm * n) %>%
  adorn_totals("row",,,,l, n, offspring)
```

Returns:

```
    l   m    lm n offspring
 0.30   0     0 1     0.000
 0.80 0.8  0.64 1     0.640
 0.90 2.3  2.07 1     2.070
 0.75 4.1 3.075 1     3.075
 0.25 2.1 0.525 1     0.525
 3.00   -     - 5     6.310
```

Along with the warning:

> Because the first column was specified to be totaled, it does not contain the label 'Total' (or user-specified name) in the totals row