# add a total row in a dplyr code but just under a specifc colum

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, row, janitor

I have this data set

```
structure(list(col2 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2), col1 = c("R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    col1 = c("L", "R", "R", "R"), col2 = c(2, 1, 2, 3), .rows = structure(list(
        6L, c(1L, 2L, 5L, 9L), c(3L, 7L, 10L), c(4L, 8L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))
```

what I would like to do is just add only a final row under 'n' column (the new created with dplyr) wit column total. I have tried with this code, but I get total for every columns.

```
library(janitor)
    data %>% 
       group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = recode(col1, 'R (change file name)' = 'R', 
                                             'L (change name e data EEG file)' = 'L')) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
      adorn_totals("row")
```

I would be eager to learn how to fix it or other strategy for this purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we could do it with `adorn_totals`:

`adorn_totals` has a `...` argument: Using ... requires specifying values for the other arguments, even if they're empty, thus the ,,,, below to accept the default values for those arguments. See original answer by @Sam Firke [Calculating and Appending Column Totals of Select Columns in a Data Frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69745242/calculating-and-appending-column-totals-of-select-columns-in-a-data-frame-in-r)

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = recode(col1, 'R (change file name)' = 'R', 
                       'L (change name e data EEG file)' = 'L')) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  adorn_totals("row",,,,n) 


  col1 col2  n
     L    2  1
     R    1  4
     R    2  3
     R    3  2
 Total    - 10
```

Comment: Nice use of `adorn_totals`!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `bind_rows` to add a row with `summarise` which has `sum` for n and total for col1. Your first `summarise` has been changed to `reframe` to have an ungrouped dataframe like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = recode(col1, 'R (change file name)' = 'R', 
                       'L (change name e data EEG file)' = 'L')) %>% 
  reframe(n = n()) %>%
  bind_rows(summarise(., across(n, sum), across(col1, ~ "Total")))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   col1   col2     n
#>   <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 L         2     1
#> 2 R         1     4
#> 3 R         2     3
#> 4 R         3     2
#> 5 Total    NA    10
```

---

Old answer with different dataset from OP:

You could use the `adorn_totals` function from the `janitor` package like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

data %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = recode(col2, 'R (change file name)' = 'R', 
                       'L (change name e data EEG file)' = 'L')) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  adorn_totals("row")
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'col1'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#>   col1                            col2  n
#>      L L (change name e data EEG file)  1
#>      R                               R  8
#>      R            R (change file name)  1
#>  Total                               - 10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I had made a mistake in reporting te dataset. Now it describe better my case

Comment: Just curious, what is the differenc between your code and OP code?

Comment: No one actually. The first dataset I have reported here was wrong. Now there is the correct one

Comment: Hi @alias, I updated my answer according to your new dataset!

Comment: Thanks @Quinten. In the adorn_totals() function istructons, I have read taht it is possible too to make this operation, by specifying the column  you are interested to get the total from with a tidyselect method. Actually I cannot figure this out, though

Comment: the function reframe() does not exist on my end

Comment: `reframe` is from the latest `dplyr` version 1.1.0, please check [this](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/reframe.html). You could also use `summarise() %>% ungroup()`.